# Boost.python void pointer functions

Tags: python, c++, boost

I have this function which creates an Object which has to be passed to other classes in the code, Im trying to get python to create the object so I can pass it as one of the parameter in other functions that Im gonna expose too python.

```
Encoder *mEncode;
Decoder *mDecode;

void *Create()
{
  Obj *obj = new Obj();
  obj->mEncode = 0;
  obj->mDecode = 0;
  return (void*)obj;
}
```

Declaring the objects and then using them

```
//init lib
void* mObj;

mObj = Create();

//pass it to the function
void encode(int mode, void *mObj);
```

Im trying recreate this in Boost.Python I started to write but rightfully fails is it possible?

```
#include "Lib_api.h"

#include <boost/python.hpp>

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(wrapper)
{
  using namespace boost::python;
  Py_Initialize();

  def("GetVersion", GetVersion);

  //Possible via python?
  mCore = Create()

}
```

Comment: That is horrible C++ code, which I'd refactor first. BTW: This can't work, because typeless objects don't exist in Python. How to do it properly depends on what this is supposed to represent and how you want to use it. BTW, as a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I appreciate your comments the code is simplified from the orginal just to show what Im trying to which is a void that sets up encode / decode to expose to other not yet written functions that need this object. Ive reworked my question as suggest if its not possible then fair enough.

Comment: I recommend checking out pybind and not using boost python

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I guess still im gonna  have to think how this can be approached.